# Firebase Function/ Express: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, firebase, express

I've mostly utilised the Hapi framework to build RESTful APIs. For this project I'm using Express and I'm a bit lost as to why this is happening.

When I test the POST endpoint using Postman, the first request is fine, but I would get an error when I make the second request.

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

The code for the route handler is below:

```js
const login = (req, res) => {
  const validation = authScema.loginPayload.validate(req.body)
  if (validation.error) {
    return res.status(400).send(validation.error.details[0].message)
  }

  const { email, password } = req.body

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(error => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid login details.')
      }
    })

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      const userObject = {
        email: user.email,
        uid: user.uid
      }
      const token = jwt.sign(userObject, secret)
      return res.status(200).send(token)
    }
  })
}
```

I don't understand why headers are resent since in every branch, I return. It should have exited the function, right?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, `signInWithEmailAndPassword`
is a promise that returns the user in the happy path

So, the following is the final code:

```js
firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => {
      const userObject = {
        email: user.email,
        uid: user.uid
      }

      const token = jwt.sign(userObject, secret)
      res.status(200).json({ token })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid login details.' })
      }
    })
```

The `onOnAuthStateChanged` is not necessary in this case.